# Are there shopkeepers in DoomRL?

Tags: doomrl

I started playing [DoomRL](http://doom.chaosforge.org/) today, and have already maxed out my inventory with a bunch of duplicates of weapons I already have, mostly pistols. Is there any way for me sell these, or should I just use up what ammo they have in them and then drop them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Woah, I never expected such a question :D.

No, there are no shopkeepers in DoomRL, nor will there ever be. Duplicate guns are useless, unless:

- you want to quickly swap between them (using Prepared slot)
- you want to mod some of them later
- a second pistol might be useful if you want to go for Dualgunner
- BFG's are nice to carry cells (they carry 100, while a cell stack is 50)

Also, note that using "U" you can unload a weapon *on the ground* or in the inventory.

Comment: Should that be "duplicate guns are **not** useless"?

Comment: ...or "duplicate guns are useless, unless:"? Great answer.

Comment: @jason, a peculiar typo between useless and unless :P

Comment: 6 years later that tip about the U key is still good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are no shopkeepers in the current version of the game. Scavenge the ammo and ditch the guns.